# html validation error on equal sign

Tags: html, validation

My html is not validating due to this line:

```
<div id="thumbsGallery"> [+content+] <a href='image.php?imagepath=[+imagePath+]&amp;title=[+imageTitle+]&amp;description=[+imageDescription+]'> <img src='[+thumbPath+]' alt="thumb path "class='thumb' title='[+imageTitle+]' id="thumb" /> </a> </div>
```

The message error are these ones: - Couldn't find end of Start Tag img line 10
                                   AND ALSO attributes construct error.

it says the problem is in the = after descprition.

Can someone see the problem?

Comment: What are you using to validate? Could it be `"c` in here: `alt="thumb path "class='`?

Comment: yes was that!! thank you. how can I reward you??

Comment: You're welcome! If you think this might be useful for other people, I can write it as an answer so you can accept it. If not, you can delete the question and remember I'm still glad to help. :)

Comment: ok write it as an answer and will accept. it might help who knows

Comment: Alright, wrote a simple explanation. Btw. you should mention what validator you were using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your HTML string you have this:

```
alt="thumb path "class='thumb'
```

Seems like the validator you're using doesn't like `"c` (no space), and it treats the whole `alt="thumb path "class` as an attribute name thus complaining about the equal sign in it.

Comment: I used W3C Markup Validation Service